# AWS ECS: Issue when access external network

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, amazon-elb

I have an issue regarding to AWS VPC networking, I want to access external API from my ECS task, I've configured ECS in a Private subnet and the only way to access this ECS is trough an load balancer, in some services like Lambda is working (I can access external resources) but in ECS I can't access to them, I tried modifying the security group rules + modify ACL rules but isn't working, If anyone know how I can do, I be very grateful, thanks.

ps: I created the VPC on the UI that AWS has.

Comment: It's unclear how you are testing Lambda functions, and how that is in any way related to the ECS tasks. Are the Lambda functions configured to run in the same subnet as the ECS tasks? If not, then those Lambda functions are irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For resources in a private subnet to access the Internet, the only option is to send that traffic through a NAT Gateway.

You will have to create an [AWS NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) in at least one of the public subnets of your VPC, and then add a route in each of the private subnets to that NAT Gateway.

Comment: @curiouscheese then ask that as a new question on here instead of tacking on to other questions please.